# Dynamic SQL in Informatica

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql, informatica

I have a mapping that is executing dynamic sql via a SQL transformation.  The dynamic sql is stored in an Oracle table and I need to add a string parameter to this query.

In this example query, the values compared to COL4 and COL5 are output correctly in the log, but the value compared to COL6 is output as '$$STRING_PARA' in the query -

```
'SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL4 = $$NUMERIC_PARA
   AND COL5 = ''Y''
   AND COL6 = ''||$$STRING_PARA||'' '
```

$$STRING_PARA is being output correctly at the beginning of the log.  I have tried omitting the pipes and increasing the number of quotes but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Maybe just `AND COL6 = $$STRING_PARA`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to run the query by replacing the Informatica input variables with the  values of the mapping. It might work like this

```
 ' SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL4 = $$NUMERIC_PARA
   AND COL5 = ''Y''
   AND COL6 = ''$$STRING_PARA'' '
```

In PL/SQL

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited echo on lines 200
SQL> @test.sql
SQL> declare
  2  v_query varchar2(4000) := ' SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE
  3    WHERE COL4 = $$NUMERIC_PARA
  4     AND COL5 = ''Y''
  5     AND COL6 = ''$$STRING_PARA'' ' ;
  6  begin
  7  dbms_output.put_line(v_query);
  8  end;
  9  /
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL4 = $$NUMERIC_PARA
   AND COL5 = 'Y'
   AND COL6 = '$$STRING_PARA'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Runtime replacement and execution by replacing input variables

```
SQL>  select object_id, object_name from dba_objects where object_name = 'MY_TEST' ;

 OBJECT_ID OBJECT_NAME
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   8897475 MY_TEST

SQL> @test.sql 8897475 MY_TEST
SQL> declare
  2  v_query varchar2(4000) := ' SELECT count(*) from dba_objects
  3    WHERE object_id = &1
  4     AND object_name = ''&2'' ' ;
  5  v_counter pls_integer;
  6  begin
  7  dbms_output.put_line(v_query);
  8  execute immediate v_query into v_counter;
  9  dbms_output.put_line('Counter is '||v_counter||' ');
 10  end;
 11  /
old   3:   WHERE object_id = &1
new   3:   WHERE object_id = 8897475
old   4:    AND object_name = ''&2'' ' ;
new   4:    AND object_name = ''MY_TEST'' ' ;
SELECT count(*) from dba_objects
  WHERE object_id = 8897475
   AND object_name = 'MY_TEST'
Counter is 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

It should work the same way, as the escaping for the single quote should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions - ''$$STRING_PARA'' worked.

I couldn't see that at the time as there was another issue in the mapping that prevented it from working correctly.